# An error while deploying ear on local websphere in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, websphere, ear

I'm trying to deploy an ear on WAS using Intellij's IBM Websphere configuration.

I see the following log:

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
Log file started at: [11/11/20 8:41:45:679 NZDT]
************* End Display Current Environment *************
Nov 11, 2020 8:41:49 AM com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory
WARNING: ADMC0046W: The system failed to load properties from com.ibm.SOAP.configURL: file:null/properties/soap.client.props
Nov 11, 2020 8:41:50 AM com.ibm.ws.management.connector.interop.JMXClassLoader
WARNING: Could not find tmx4jTransform.jar in null/etc/tmx4jTransform.jar - Interoperability to older versions of WebSphere is disabled
Nov 11, 2020 8:41:50 AM com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager
INFO: CWPKI0051I: The process has the java security property jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms set to [MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224].  The WebSphere Application server is setting the java security property jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms to [MD2, RSA keySize < 1024, MD5]. 
Nov 11, 2020 8:41:50 AM com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager
INFO: CWPKI0051I: The process has the java security property jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms set to [SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, DESede, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL].  The WebSphere Application server is setting the java security property jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms to [SSLv3, RC4, DH keySize < 768, MD5withRSA]. 
Nov 11, 2020 8:41:50 AM com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager
INFO: CWPKI0027I: Disabling default hostname verification for HTTPS URL connections.
Nov 11, 2020 8:41:50 AM com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityObjectLocator
INFO: CWSCF0002I: The client code is attempting to load the security configuration the server and this operation is not allowed.
Nov 11, 2020 8:41:50 AM com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory
WARNING: ADMC0046W: The system failed to load properties from com.ibm.SOAP.configURL: file:null/properties/soap.client.props
Nov 11, 2020 8:41:51 AM com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory
```

Configuration is pretty standard, nothing different.
Doing this on a windows OS, with WAS version being 8.5.17 and latest version of Intellij.

[image: Server Setup]

[image]

[image]

Edit:
When I do a refresh, I see this

```
[2020-11-11 08:55:40,808] Artifact xyz-ear:ear: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
```

So, essentially Intellij is not able to establish connection with the websphere.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA. Please attach the full output from the run console as text and also attach the generated start script `.cmd` file (the full name is in the first line of the console output). Were there any modifications to your WAS installation configs? Make sure user/password is set for JMX, [see this comment for details](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247460#focus=Comments-27-4321549.0-0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had exactly the same symptom and we have 2 different solutions for this (tested on 2020.3):
Via Windows cmd line:
mklink /D Program%20Files "Program Files"

via IntelliJ:
Menu Help/Edit Custom VM Options...
Add the following VM option and restart IntelliJ:
-Didea.dynamic.classpath=true

Comment: I have done something similar to get it working, just moved my WAS on non Program files location, worked.